# How to delete one history entry in Safari on iOS?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, history, browser-history

On iOS, I have the history of Safari.

I want to delete some entries one by one. Is this possible ? I have tried going left — to no avail.

I have an iPad mini on iOS 7.

Comment: On iOS8 is possible if you swipe left. Can't test on iOS 7 device right now.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 8, I can delete an entry from the history by sliding left on it and clicking Delete.

This is a very nice addition. :-)